# JavaScript Traverse Table Issue

Tags: javascript, html, html-table, children

Why does this script bail out (IE) or stick (FF) at the first table cell containing text that it finds?

```
<!html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function CheckChildren(obj)
{
        alert(obj.id + ' ' + obj.tagName + ' ' + obj.childNodes.length);
        for ( i = 0; i < obj.childNodes.length; i++)
        {
                CheckChildren(obj.childNodes[i]);
        }
        alert(obj.id);
        return false;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<table id="table">
<tr id="a"><td id="b">b</td><td id="c">c</td></tr>
<tr id="d"><td id="e">e</td><td id="f">f</td></tr>
</table>
<input type="button" onclick="CheckChildren(document.getElementById('table'))" value="click">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I had started to use the following instead:

        for (i = 0; i < obj.rows.length; i++)
                for (j = 0; j < obj.rows[i].cells.length; j++)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try putting the word "var" before the "i" in your for loop.

```
  for ( var i = 0; i < obj.childNodes.length; i++)
```

Without that, your code is referring to a global variable "i", so each recursive iteration sets it back to zero.